# Extracting locatation information from Google Maps and business directories

Tags: google-maps, batch, address, download

Is there a way to mass download/extract (infrastructure) data from either Google Maps or Business directories based on a search query?

I am often asked to create inventories of assets within a local authority such as places of worship, schools or hospitals. Currently I just do a Google Map search and extract each name and address manually before geo-referencing in Mapinfo which is very time consuming. Is there a tool which will download all this information automatically (name, address, postcode, phone number) from Google Maps or 118118, or is copy/pasting the results the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is possible to write a bot for getting those information, but sooner or later you will either hit a legal issue or a query limit (cf. Section C of 118118 terms on bulk downloads).

For bulk operations I would recommend setting up your own instance of the OpenStreetMap server with Overpass API, where you can find the necessary information.

First you may test the API on existing instance (the requests might take several seconds to complete, even for small areas), although using them excesively will be considered bad manners by the community (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#Introduction):

- [places of worship](http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[amenity=place_of_worship][bbox=-2.2550954159407,51.85882081683,-2.2393669422773,51.8722698767])

Comment: Ok thank you for your input. When searching for information about the API you mentioned, I came across http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/downloading_osm_data.html which seems suitable, although I have yet to try it.

Comment: That would probably be a better approach, since data are the same but no need for setting up your own server.